# bash shell scripting: create an endtime from a starttime

Tags: bash, date

I am mediating some data from one file-format to another and am using bash to perform the mediation steps. Part of the process involves taking a timestamp from the filename to create a starttime and then adding 5 minutes to that to create the endtime. The filename gives me a date in this format YYYYmmddHHMMSS. I can easily add 500 to each starttime to get an endtime that works for all starttimes except 55 mins past the hour but this obviously not correct so I have tried to use the `date --date=` code to add the 5minutes like this:

```
date --date='$starttime +5 minutes' '+%Y%m%d%H%M%S'
```

for example:

```
date --date='20140220125500 +5 minutes' '+%Y%m%d%H%M%S'
```

However I get an error like this every time:

> date: invalid date `20140220125500 +5 minutes'

Can anyone suggest what I need to change in my date statement or if there is a similar alternative syntax available?

Comment: also, if you want to use $starttime in the quotes, you should use *double* quotes, not simple quotes.

Comment: try to come up with the shortest testcase. e.g. this was my first check: `date: invalid date 20140220125500`
`

Comment: agreed about the double quotes, typo from code to webpage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked to me:

```
$ date --date='20140220 12:55:00 CET +5 minutes' '+%Y%m%d%H%M%S'
20140220130000
```

That is, the problem is that `YYYYYMMDDHHMMSS` alone is not understandable for `date`. Instead, give it on the `YYYYYMMDD HH:MM:SS` format.

As you are receiving the data on that `YYYYYMMDDHHMMSS` format, you can parse it with `sed` as follows:

```
$ file="YYYYmmddHHMMSS"
$ new_name=$(sed -e 's/^\(.\{8\}\)\(.\{2\}\)\(.\{2\}\)\(.\{2\}\)/\1 \2:\3:\4/' <<< "$file")
$ echo "$new_name"
YYYYmmdd HH:MM:SS
```

So in your case:

```
$ file="20140220125500"
$ new_name=$(sed -e 's/^\(.\{8\}\)\(.\{2\}\)\(.\{2\}\)\(.\{2\}\)/\1 \2:\3:\4/' <<< "$file")
$ echo "$new_name"
20140220 12:55:00
$ date --date="$new_name CET + 5 minutes"
Thu Feb 20 13:00:00 CET 2014
```

Note I used

```
$ date --date="$new_name CET +5 minutes" '+%Y%m%d%H%M%S'
              ^                        ^
              note the double quotes to have the var expanded
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'll give this a try...one question though, your conversion output of 20140220085600 isn't the right format. I've retried that on the command line and I get something similar. Is there any reason it's not coming out in the format specified: %Y%m%d%H%M%S.

Comment: It is true, just noticed it. I tried adding `CET` and it works. See my updated answer.

Comment: agreed! works on command line for me too with GMT now. Thanks. I'll add the sed code and test the script and post back later.

Comment: All working, thanks. Tick toggled to green :-D

Yes I'm a newbie on here, used to use shell scripting a fair bit but haven't touched it for years so a little rusty. Good fun though.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Then re-welcome in the track :) Hope to see you again around, I every day learn more and more here and I am sure you will be able to add much of your rusty knowledge :)!